# Nonstop working function in threads

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, runnable

I have class XYZ that implements Runnable with method run() . I making thread of it, then use .run() and after that I "put him to sleep" for some time. Is there any elegant way to run my function  in method run() of class XYZ non-stop (do smth,sleep(),do smth,sleep... etc), until I turn off JFrame (where program shows his results). I came up with idea of loop that never ends (it works in the end) , but I guess that's not very elegant and competent solution.

Comment: Your question appears to devolve to -- "How do I stop one thread from within another", no?

Comment: I'd like to run for example threads, that run some function non-stop (every single thread) . For example i want to have 5  running threads , where every single will give me pseudo random double value from different range (each thread have diffrent range) every 1 second .So every 1 second I will get 5 different double figure.

Comment: This is no different from the thousands of previous similar questions. Please look at the dup used to close this question as well as the many more that you can find.

Comment: [Link to dups on the general question](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how+to+stop+one+thread+in+java+site:http:%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F), as well as [links to dups as it applies to Swing GUI's](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how+to+stop+one+thread+in+java+swing+gui+site:http:%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F)

Comment: That's not what I need to work out , anyway thank you for your time !!! I'll do something simillar to the solution from answer of this question .

Comment: Sorry but you're very confused. Note that the solution is just a small example of stopping threads, similar to some mentioned in the duplicate, so yes it **is** what you need to work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private boolean shutDown;

public void run()
{
    while (!shutDown)
    {
        //Do Something
        Thread.sleep(500)
    }
}
public void shutDown()
{
    shutDown = true
}
```

Comment: I guess that will work fine. Came up on similar solution. Anyway thank you for answer.